# Recursion confuses me

Tags: prolog

I have understood the theory part of Recursion. I have seen exercises but I get confused. I've tried to solve some, some I understand and some I don't. This exercise is confusing me. I can't understand why, so I use comments to show you my weak points. I should have power (X,N,P) so  P=X^N.
Some examples:

```
?- power(3,5,X).
X = 243
?- power(4,3,X).
X = 64
?- power(2,4,X).
X = 16
```

The solution of this exercise is: (See comments too)

```
power(X,0,1).      % I know how works recursion,but those numbers 0 or 1 why? 
power(X,1,X).      % X,1,X i can't get it.
power(X,N,P) :-    % X,N,P if only 
   N1 is N-1,      % N1=N-1 ..ok i understand
   power(X,N1,P1), % P1 is used to reach the the P
   P is P1*X.      % P = P1*X
```

What I know recursion, I use a different my example

```
related(X, Y) :-              
   parent(X, Z),                 
   related(Z, Y).
```

Compare my example with the exercise. I could say that my first line, what I think. Please help me out with it is a lot of confusing.

`related(X, Y) :-` is similar to `power(X,N,P) :-` . Second sentence of my example `parent(X, Z),`  is similar to  `N1 is N-1,`  and the third sentence is `related(Z, Y).`   similar to  `power(X,N1,P1),` and   `P is P1*X.`.

Comment: Well x^0=1 and x^1=x, that's just maths you need to learn

Comment: yes,but why he use it as an answer?there are randoms numbers or it used for the exercise?

Comment: Because recursion requires at least 1 base case and recursive case, they are base cases. And they are not random numbers, they are just equations you need to know

Comment: example he could use not 0 and not 1 but another numbers?like 2,3 etc?his choice was?

Comment: Their choice was a fundamental rule of indices in mathematics. It doesn't work for any other numbers. If you need help understanding that you need to study maths

Comment: in every recursive case can be used those?because i don't see in any example like those..So ,to solve this exercise it required those sentences power(X,0,1). and power(X,1,X).

Comment: Read and understand [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) (especially integer exponentiation), then read your recursion notes again. Because this example is very much theory, I don't believe you've understood it.

Comment: ok thanks a lot,i will wrote back if i still have questions ,it is very confusing

Comment: @m.n in Prolog you define rules. In this case, a rule is being defined called `power(B, E, X)` which means that `X` is the value of `B` taken to the power `E`. So, `power(X, 0, 1)`, as Nick points out, just means *if you take `X` to the power 0 you get 1*. And `power(X, 1, X)` means *if you take `X` to the power 1 you get `X`*. Then you need a general rule which can be written recursively: the rule for `power(X, N, P)` tells you how to take `X` to the `N` power giving `P`. It defines it in terms of an exponent whose value is `N-1`. Basic recursion.

Comment: @NickA: "Well x^0=1 and x^1=x, that's just maths".  But isn't 0^0=1 rather CS?

Comment: @false 0^0 has been an ongoing debate for a long time, there isn't a standard anywhere, even the IEEE floating point standard has 2 different values for it, 1 and NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go over the definition of the predicate step by step. First you have the fact...

```
power(X,0,1).
```

... that states: *The 0th power of any* `X` *is* `1`. Then there is the fact...

```
power(X,1,X).
```

... that states: *The 1st power of any* `X` *is* `X` *itself.* Finally, you have a recursive rule that reads:

```
power(X,N,P) :-    % P is the Nth power of X     if 
   N1 is N-1,      % N1 = N-1                    and
   power(X,N1,P1), % P1 is the N1th power of X   and
   P is P1*X.      % P = P1*X
```

Possibly your confusion is due to the two base cases that are expressed by the two facts (one of those is actually superfluous). Let's consider the following queries:

```
?- power(5,0,X).
X = 1 ;
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

The answer `1` is certainly what we expect, but then the predicate loops until it runs out of stack. That's certainly not desirable. And this query...

```
?- power(5,1,X).
X = 5 ;
X = 5 ;
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

... yields the correct answer twice before running out of stack. The reason for the redundant answer is that the recursive rule can reduce any given `N` to zero *and* to one thus yielding the same answer twice. If you look at the structure of your recursive rule, it is obvious that the first base case is sufficient, so let's remove the second. The reason for looping out of stack is that, after `N` becomes zero, the recursive rule will search for other solutions (for `N=-1`, `N=-2`, `N=-3`,...) that do not exist. To avoid that, you can add a goal that prevents the recursive rule from further search, if `N` is equal to or smaller than zero. That leaves you with following definition:

```
power(X,0,1).      % the 0th power of any X is 1
power(X,N,P) :-    % P is the Nth power of X     if
   N > 0,          % N > 0                       and
   N1 is N-1,      % N1 = N-1                    and
   power(X,N1,P1), % P1 is the N1th power of X   and
   P is P1*X.      % P = P1*X
```

Now the predicate works as expected:

```
?- power(5,0,X).
X = 1 ;
false.

?- power(5,1,X).
X = 5 ;
false.

?- power(5,3,X).
X = 125 ;
false.
```

I hope this alleviates some of your confusions.